# Media module - CKEditor embed not working - jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, media

I'm trying to use the media module along with CKEditor in a Drupal7 build.
I've enabled the modules, added the embed media button to the editor's toolbar and it works to a point - the image uploads, and styles/variations created. But I can't actually embed it as the final screen of the overlay (type in alt text, choose size etc) the buttons stay as 'fake' buttons.

Looking in console the error is Jquery is not defined.

Anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by changing the admin jquery version down to 1.7 using the Jquery Update settings.

Comment: That is usually the right way to handle this issue. Newer jQuery versions are not compatible with admin forms. You will notice the same thing in the Views UI.